# Reading and writing files "simultaneously" in different processes

Tags: java, file, io, ipc

I've got two Java processes, `Processor` and `Simulator`. The `Simulator` writes to `File X` a prescribed data record (10 lines of text) every 5s. The `Processor` reads this file continually, waiting for tokens to indicate a valid record. The code is this (with some substitutions for filenames):

In `Simulator`, every 5s:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(DATA_FILE, true);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
bufferedWriter.write(DATA);
bufferedWriter.close();
```

In `Processor`, constantly:

```
mScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader(DATA_FILE)));
mScanner.useLocale(Locale.UK);

while (true) {              
    while (mScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // Parse the data bundle.
    if (parseDataBundle()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Previously, the `Processor` was hooked to an `InputStream` and there was no problem using the `Scanner` (configured appropriately) to read data as it arrived.

Here, I can see that the data is being written correctly *when it is generated* by refreshing the file in Notepad. But when using a file rather than an InputStream, the `if ( parseDataBundle()) {` line is never reached.

What am I doing wrong? The `Processor` seems to have hold of the file resource, since I can't delete it whilst it's running. My gut thinks it's probably something to do with a misuse of concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's a misuse of files.  Files are not a designed for messaging.  Once you have reached the end of the file, that is it.  The only way to avoid this is to make sure you only read when you know there is more data (by checking the length)  This is more complicated when using text.

You can use files with text but it is tricky. You have to have one thread polling the file size and when it changes, read just the bytes added (and no more). This can be written to a pipe. Your reading thread can read from the pipe using InputStreamReader and BufferedReader.

---

To vary the polling interval you can use an escalating sleep interval like

```
long lastSize = 
int maxSleep = 5000, sleep = 200;
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     long size = file.length();
     if (size > lastSize) {
        copyData(size - lastSize);
        lastSize = size;
        sleep = 200;
     } else {
        Thread.sleep(sleep);
        sleep += 200;
        if (sleep > maxSleep)
            sleep = maxSleep;
}
```

The benefit of this approach is the that time it sleeps for adjusts to the rate it gets messages.

Comment: I can have the simulator write to anything, but it certainly needs to write text in that prescribed way, since the hardware its emulating does that. The real hardware uses RS232 to communicate, so I could bolt the simulator onto this and use the InputStream as before but I'd rather do it with zero hardware.

How would I use a Socket here?

Comment: Sending messages via sockets is much simpler to read from.  You can use files with text but it is tricky.  You have to have one thread polling the file size and when it changes, read just the bytes added (and no more).  This can be written to a pipe. Your reading thread can read from the pipe using InputStreamReader and BufferedReader.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll have a look into this - looks like it'll be a neat solution.

Comment: @EdKing I have added some code on how to have the sleep interval self adjusting.

Comment: I've implemented a server/client model using sockets and it's all looking good! Thanks @PeterLawrey.

Comment: @EdKing You can write everything to the file or logs as well for your records.

Answer (score 0):

Java NIO provides File locking support. Depending on the underlying OS- you can obtain exclusive lock on the file while writing and release lock after your writing is complete. Another process can try to acquire lock, if it gets, read the file and release it. Poll till you acquire lock. Hope you get the idea. Look at [FileChannel#lock()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29) API.